# Simplifying trig expression cos and sin.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm reading a solution right now, and I am stuck.

$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) - \cos\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)\theta}{2} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) =\frac{\sin(n\frac{\theta}{2}))\sin\left(\left[n+1\right]\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$$

How could these two equations be equal.

Comment: Do you have your own thought?

Comment: @Shuchang I posted this because I don't have any thought.

Comment: @therexists you still should post what you have tried, other wise you might end up with hints like: "use trigonometrical properties", and also, whay did you tag this in abstract algebra?

Comment: @AnaGalois Because this problem is from abstract algebra book. I will edit to post what I have tried now.

Comment: @Dre You edited my post wrongly.... sin(theta/2) should be in the denominator of LHS.

Comment: @therexists My apologies. I am unable to fix that, but someone else can.

Comment: Is the problem correct?? I think there are typos.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha Not yet. The only thing needs to be corrected is sin(theta/2) should be in the denominator of left hand side. So denominator of LHS is 2*sin(theta/2)

Comment: I wish I can post my work, but I don't have idea for this...

Comment: I also think $\cos(n+1/2)\theta$ in the LHS should be actually $\cos\{(n+1)\theta/2\}$. Because then the RHS will be exactly equal to the LHS.

Comment: @therexists Is this your original problem?: $${\cos (\frac {\theta}{2}) - \cos(n+(\frac12\theta)) \over 2\sin(\frac {\theta}{2})}= {\sin(n\frac{\theta}{2})\sin ((n+1) \frac {\theta}{2})) \over \sin(\frac {\theta}{2})}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the accuracy/format of the problem as

using $\displaystyle \cos C-\cos D=2\sin\frac{C+D}2\sin\frac{D-C}2$

$$\cos\frac\theta2-\cos\left(n+\frac12\right)\theta=2\sin\frac{n\theta}2\sin\frac{(n+1)\theta}2 $$